# How to prove the reliability of a predictive model to executives?

Tags: machine-learning, data-modeling, modeling, prediction, training-data

I trained data from 500 devices to predict their performance. Then I applied my trained model to a test data set for another 500 devices and show pretty good prediction results. Now my executives want me to prove this model will work well on one million devices not only on 500. Obviously we don't have data for one million devices. And if the model is not reliable, they want me to discover the required amount of train data in order to make a reliable prediction on one million devices. How should I deal with these executives who don't have a background in statistical analysis and modeling? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I suspect there will be statistical models for this, but I also suspect they require a lot more specific data. I don't know much about machine learning, so it could easily be my fault, but your description seems very vague to me.

Comment: This is not a problem of the executives not knowing about machine learning. Their point is valid. It is possible that your training and testing set are not representative of your whole data space and that your model only works for this biased subset but fails to generalize for all data. You have to show them that the small data set you sampled is unbiased. The problem is simple to understand. Consider e.g. that the training and testing set only contains male customers. Even if the model works well it may perform poorly on a real data set with male and female customers.

Comment: @cel Thanks for your response. Your point is absolutely valid. Is there any correlation between the size of train set and the reliability of model? Because in the next step I need to show them that the random selected train set is big enough to build a reliable model.

Comment: @cel  Your response is the correct one. I'd recommend throwing it out there as an answer to the OP (and I will upvote as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have suggested to @cep to write up his comment as an answer - including providing the `variance` and `bias` calculations. In any case it could be added

> "Do not be quick to assume Execs are essentially incapable in terms of
>   technical or mathematical concepts"

While there may be `Dilbert` managers out there .. *somewhere* I have seen few of them myself. More often managers get to their positions through hard work. They are likely to be rusty - but the abilities are likely still there.

In this case whether or not they have a "background in statistical analysis and modeling" they are applying common sense.

The first thing you might do is to provide the proper context and terminology.  @cel has mentioned some of it: providing concrete values for :

- assumptions

  - what assumptions are you making about the data.
  - What basis is there to consider extrapolation of the limited data
  - why should said extrapoated results be trusted to apply to the 99.5% of untested data
- data distribution

  - basic descriptive statistics
  - your take on the apriori distribution of the data. Justify why you chose it
- modeling

  - which models/approaches were considered and why
  - which model you actually chose and why
  - how did you arrive at the hyperparameters
  - how you trained the model
- results

  - statistical measures of fit and error rate